# An unbiased estimate for population variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, population, finite-population

Specifically, my notes claim that when calculating confidence intervals for population proportion $p$, the estimator for the population variance is given by $\frac{P_sQ_s}{n}$, where $P_s=\frac{X}{n}$ is the random variable for the proportion of successes. Thus we have $E(P_s)=p$ and Var$(P_s)=\frac{pq}{n}$. My question is, shouldn't we have $\frac{P_sQ_s}{n} \times \frac{n}{n-1}$ as the unbiased estimator instead?

Also, from my understanding, we say that $T$ is an (unbiased) estimator of the population parameter $\theta$ if we have $E(T)=\theta$. So is there any way to prove/disprove $E(\frac{P_sQ_s}{n})=\sigma^2$, where $\sigma^2$ is the population variance?

Comment: Do your notes claim this is an unbiased estimator?

Comment: Nope it does not, I was just wondering if it was. Thanks so much for the answer! Just saw it now, will read through it carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably $Q_s(X) = 1 - P_s(X) = (n-X)/n.$

Writing $q=1-p$, let's work out the expectation of $n^2P_s(X)Q_s(X)$ using the definition of expectation, the formula for Binomial probabilities, and the Binomial Theorem:

$$\eqalign{
E\left[n^2P_s(X)Q_s(X)\right] &= E\left[X(n-X)\right] \\
&= \sum_x \Pr(X=x)\, x(n-x) & \text{(Definition of expectation)} \\
&= \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x}p^x q^{n-x}\, x(n-x) &\text{(Binomial distribution)} \\
&=\sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x}\, pq \frac{\partial^2}{\partial p\partial q} \left(p^x\,q^{n-x}\right) \\
&=  pq \frac{\partial^2}{\partial p\partial q}\sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x}\, p^x\,q^{n-x} & \text{(Linearity of differentiation)}\\
&= pq \frac{\partial^2}{\partial p\partial q}\left(p+q\right)^n &\text{(Binomial Theorem)}\\
&= pq\,n(n-1)(p+q)^{n-2}.
}$$

(When $n=1$ or $n=0$ the result is just $0.$)  Plugging in $p+q=1$ gives

$$E\left[n^2P_sQ_s\right]  = n(n-1)pq$$

for all $n,$ whence for $n\gt 1,$

$$E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\,P_s(X)Q_s(X)\right] = \frac{pq}{n}=\operatorname{Var}\left(P_s(X)\right).$$

Therefore $P_s(X)Q_s(X)/(n-1)$ is an unbiased estimator of the variance of $X/n$ (and so obviously $P_s(X)Q_s(X)/n$ is not: it is biased).

Comment: Why then isn't the unbiased estimator used?

Comment: @Jon Since the parameter $p$ is estimated by the sample mean (in an unbiased way), and that in turn determines the population variance, it is rare for anyone to need a separate estimate of the population variance in a Binomial setting or to be able to do anything useful with it that cannot already be carried out with the estimate of $p.$

Comment: What about for example for a confidence interval for $p$?

Comment: @Jon Most of them just use the estimate of $p.$ (There are many confidence interval procedures for Binomial data: search our site for "Clopper" to find the best summaries.)  Intuitively it wouldn't make much sense to employ a separate estimate of the variance that was inconsistent with the estimate of $p$--and the simple mathematical fact is that any estimate of the variance that is a (known) constant multiple of another will give the same procedure.  The only thing that changes is how you describe it.

Comment: I like the differentiation trick. How did you think of that?

Comment: @darkgbm That's a standard technique in combinatorics.  Research *formal power series.*

Comment: Now that I think about it again, I don't understand something. Let's say $n=2$ in the above example. Then, $0 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial p\partial q}(1) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial p\partial q}(p+q)^2 = 2$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @darkgbm $p$ and $q$ are formal variables, not numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using the following variance formula and rule

$Var(\hat{p})=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}=E[\hat{p}^2]-E[\hat{p}]^2$

where $\hat{p}$ is the sample proportion of times an indicator variable is 1 in a simple random sample of size $n$, i.e. the mean of an indicator variable, and $p$ is the corresponding population proportion for that indicator variable.

Suppose we estimate the population variance for that indicator variable, which is $p(1-p)$ (in terms of the population proportion $p$), using the estimator $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ (which uses the sample statistics only). This estimator is biased and multiplying it by $n/(n-1)$ would make it unbiased.

Proof:

$E[\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})]=E[\hat{p}-\hat{p}^2]=p-E[\hat{p}^2]$

Rearranging the variance formula and rule above, we get $E[\hat{p}^2]=p^2 + \frac{p(1-p)}{n}$. Plugging that in we get

$E[\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})]=p - p^2 - \frac{p(1-p)}{n} = \frac{n-1}{n}p(1-p)$

Comment: +1 Simple and elegant.