# Proof of Variance of Sample Proportion

Tags: variance, proportion

Can someone help me understand the following for the variance of a sample proportion.

$$ S^2 = \dfrac{\sum (y_i - p)^2}{N-1} = \dfrac{\sum y_i^2 - 2p\sum yi + Np^2 }{N-1} = \dfrac{N}{N-1}p(1-p) $$

More specifically how do you get to the last step from the second last step.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $p=\frac1N \sum y_i$ with each $y_i$ zero or one?

Comment: sorry I wrote it down wrong its fixed now

Comment: If each $y_i$ is zero or one then $y_i^2 = y_i$ so you can show the right hand equality using $\sum y_i^2=\sum y_i = Np$.

Comment: A more interesting question is the left hand equality, which suggests when $p=\frac12$ a number higher than $\frac14$ (the maximum possible variance of a Bernoulli random variable).  This is an issue about the inadmissibility of some unbiased estimators

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52542

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464110 has two different proofs that avoid this specific algebraic manipulation.